# Different result using Criteria and NearQuery using the same point and distance - Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I use POJO with lombok to represent the geometry collection.

```
@Document(collection = "geometries")
@TypeAlias(value = "geometry")
@Data
@Builder
public class GeometryObject {
    
    final static String COORDINATE_FIELD_NAME = "coordinates";       
    private @Id ObjectId id;
    private GeoJsonObjectType geometryType;
    private Map<String, String> properties;
    @GeoSpatialIndexed(type=GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE , name=COORDINATE_FIELD_NAME+"_index") 
    @Field(COORDINATE_FIELD_NAME)
    private GeoJson geometry;   
     
}
```

To have control over repository queries I am using the MongoTemple. I've implemented two variation for querying near-point with max distance.

The first;

```
@Override
public List<GeometryObject> nearPointMaxDistance(GeoJsonPoint geojsonPoint, Distance maxDistance) {
    Point point = new Point(geojsonPoint.getX(), geojsonPoint.getY());
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where(COORDINATE_FIELD_NAME).nearSphere(point).maxDistance(maxDistance.getValue());
    final Query query = new Query();                
    query.addCriteria(criteria);
    return template.find(query, GeometryObject.class);        
}
```

The second;

```
@Override
    public GeoResults<GeometryObject> geoNearPointMaxDistance(GeoJsonPoint geojsonPoint, Distance maxDistance) {                   
        final NearQuery nearQuery = NearQuery.near(geojsonPoint).maxDistance(maxDistance).spherical(true);
        return template.geoNear(nearQuery, GeometryObject.class);               
    }
```

The test case the two different near queries.

```
@BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        geometryRepo.clearGeometryCollection();
        GeoJsonPoint gbgStnPoint = new GeoJsonPoint(11.972973346710205, 57.7090537698375);
        GeometryObject gbgStnGeoObj = GeometryObject.builder().geometry(gbgStnPoint).geometryType(GeoJsonObjectType.POINT).build();
        geometryRepo.save(gbgStnGeoObj);
        GeoJsonPoint molndalStnPoint = new GeoJsonPoint(12.016907930374146, 57.65644872952383);
        molndalStnGeoObj = GeometryObject.builder().geometry(molndalStnPoint).geometryType(GeoJsonObjectType.POINT).build();
        //distFromStn = new Distance(6.42, Metrics.KILOMETERS); //The distance between the two trainstations are 6.41 km, anything greater would result in valid result.
        distFromStn = new Distance(0.01, Metrics.KILOMETERS); // The nearPointTest will be valid even when distance set to 10 meters but not 1 meter. 
    }
    
    @Test
    void nearPointTest() {
        List<GeometryObject> result = geometryRepo.nearPointMaxDistance((GeoJsonPoint)molndalStnGeoObj.getGeometry(), distFromStn);
        assertThat(result).isNotEmpty();                
        result.forEach(geo -> log.debug("Geometry result: {}", geo.toString()));
    }
    
    @Test
    void geoNearPointTest() {
       GeoResults<GeometryObject> result = geometryRepo.geoNearPointMaxDistance((GeoJsonPoint)molndalStnGeoObj.getGeometry(), distFromStn);     
       assertThat(result).isNotEmpty();
       result.forEach(geo -> log.debug("Point {} - distance from source {}", geo.getContent().toString(),geo.getDistance()));
    }
```

The distance between the points in a straight line is 6.41 km. If I run the test with distance set to 2 km, the first (nearPointTest) function still return a result. If I set distance to 6.42 km both functions passes as expected. Only when setting the distance to 0.001 km both functions fails.

*I use MongoDB 4.4.4 and Spring Data MongoDB 3.0.4.*

What am I missing, why do I get different result when using The *Criteria* opposed to *NearQuery*. They should both work with the versions (MongoDB and Spring) that i use?

Comment: Did you have a look at the [GeoJSON Section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.geo-json)? There's a difference in the unit of measure for the distance calculation. Using the legacy format operates upon Radians on an Earth like sphere, whereas the GeoJSON format uses Meters. Please feel free to open an issue on [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues). A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like the full test from above would be great to have.

Comment: Hi @ChristophStrobl. I will have a second look and test the legacy format and test if it's the radians calculation that causes the error.  And open an issue in case there is one.  Thanks.